# How to create component tree hierarchy from JSON? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

need to use the data value in tree format. It should automatically create a new node if there is another child

```
<Tree
     key={index}
     lineWidth={"2px"}
     lineColor={"green"}
     lineBorderRadius={"10px"}
     label={
            <StyledNode>
                {data.name}
            </StyledNode>
            }
    >
    {data.subordinates.map((data, index) => {
       return (
        <TreeNode
           key={index}
           label={
             <StyledNode>
                {data.name}
             </StyledNode>
                }
         ></TreeNode>
       );
   })}
 </Tree>
```

I want to create the new node on the basis of the JSON received
and sample JSON data is like;

```
export const chartData1 = [
  {
    name: "root",
    sub: [
      { name: "child1", sub: [{ name: "schild1", sub: [] }] },
      { name: "child2", sub: [{ name: "schild2", sub: [] }] },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "roo2",
    sub: [
      { name: "child1", sub: [] },
      { name: "child2 DOE", sub: [] },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest solution. Just style your `div`s as you like.

```
function TreeNode({ node }) {
  if (node.sub.length === 0) {
    return <div>{node.name}</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{node.name}</p>
        {node.sub.map(x => (
          <TreeNode node={x} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Checkout how it works in the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-johnson-e1j9v?file=/src/App.js:504-762)

Comment: if we have more child then, it is not working @Rostyslav

Comment: @SanuKumar have you checked the sandbox ?

Comment: Yes, i have checked the sandbox, but my current JSON have more number of childs

Comment: can you provide the JSON?

Comment: It does work for the JSON format which you provided...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-shape-ukui2

here is the updated one, yes it worked for provided JSON format

Comment: Here is the working example https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-franklin-poybn?file=/src/App.js . Please, mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar case.

And created a component for this feature.
might be useful for the users who are searching for the same.

A fully customizable lightweight tree generator component.

You can pass custom child and parent components for a better view

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-tree